# How do I find the index of the first non-nil element in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, null

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  If I want to find the first non-nil element of an array I can use

```
a.find { |x| !x.nil? }
```

but how do I find the index of where that first non-nil element occurred?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking, we need sample input data that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use either the `index` or `find_index` methods.

```
a.index { |x| !x.nil? }
```

> Returns the index of the first object in ary such that the object is == to obj. If a block is given instead of an argument, returns the index of the first object for which the block returns true. Returns nil if no match is found.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index

Answer (score 0):

Pro tipp, you can use the `methodsolver` gem to find methods like that

```
solve { [nil,7,7,nil,nil,nil].___ { |x| !x.nil? } == 1 }
```

Prints

```
Found 2 methods for #___
- Array#find_index
- Array#index
```

Method solver does a brute-force search over all methods on the class of the receiver and returns those where the block evaluates to true. It does a best effort to avoid dangerous methods, but best use with caution on classes that might cause dangerous side-effects.